# Wordwrap function for wrapping string in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

> NOTE: I am not asking about wrapping string in text widget.

Is there any word wrap function to word wrap a large string in dart. Builtin or via package

```
e.g. 
var str = "An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic";
print(wordwrap(str,15,"\n");
Output:
An example of a \nlong word is: \nSupercalifragulistic
```

Like this one available in PHP : [wordwrap()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_wordwrap.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Dart code for wrapping long string.
It breaks long words as well.

```
void main() {
  String string = "Comments, notes or other information about the packages will print here. Your comments go here.";

  List<String> list = _wrapLine(string, 12);

  for (String str in list)
    print(str);
}

///
/// Wrap your string.
/// @param line - String line which need to be wrapped.
/// @param wrapLength - Wrapping threshold. Must be greater than 1.
/// @return
///
List<String> _wrapLine(String line, int wrapLength) {
  List<String> resultList = [];

  if (line == null || line.length == 0) {
    resultList.add("");
    return resultList;
  }
  if (line.length <= wrapLength) {
    resultList.add(line);
    return resultList;
  }

  List<String> words = line.split(" ");

  for (String word in words) {
    if (resultList.length == 0) {
      addNewWord(resultList, word, wrapLength);
    } else {
      String lastLine = resultList.last;

      if (lastLine.length + word.length < wrapLength) {
        lastLine = lastLine + word + " ";
        resultList.last = lastLine;
      } else if (lastLine.length + word.length == wrapLength) {
        lastLine = lastLine + word;
        resultList.last = lastLine;
      } else {
        if (_isThereMuchSpace(lastLine, wrapLength.toDouble())) {
          _breakLongWord(resultList, word, wrapLength, lastLine.length);
        } else {
          addNewWord(resultList, word, wrapLength);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return resultList;
}

void addNewWord(List<String> resultList, String word, int wrapLength) {
    if (word.length < wrapLength) {
        resultList.add(word + " ");
    } else if (word.length == wrapLength) {
        resultList.add(word);
    } else {
        _breakLongWord(resultList, word, wrapLength, 0);
    }
}

void _breakLongWord(List<String> resultList, String word, int wrapLength, int offset) {
    String part = word.substring(0, (wrapLength - offset) - 1);
    if (offset > 1) {
        String lastLine = resultList.last;
        lastLine = lastLine + part + "-";
        resultList.last = lastLine;
    } else {
        resultList.add(part + "-");
    }

    String nextPart = word.substring((wrapLength - offset) - 1, word.length);
    if (nextPart.length > wrapLength)
        _breakLongWord(resultList, nextPart, wrapLength, 0);
    else if (nextPart.length == wrapLength)
        resultList.add(nextPart);
    else
        resultList.add(nextPart + " ");
}

bool _isThereMuchSpace(String line, double lineLength) {
  double expectedPercent = (lineLength * 65) / 100;
  if (line.length <= expectedPercent) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add package [basic_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils)

Use this function `StringUtils.addCharAtPosition()`:

e.g.

```
String s = 'An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic';
//This will add '\n' after every 10 positions.
print(StringUtils.addCharAtPosition(s, '\n',12,repeat:true));
/*
Output:
An example o
f a long wor
d is: Superc
alifragulist
ic
*/
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion. But this will add \n at every X character, whereas I want something which respects WORD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if you're asking about making text multiline when it reach some size then you can wrap a text into a container which limit its size and even set how many lines it can have and when it reach over these lines then set overflow behaviour

```
 SizedBox(
   width: 50,
   child: Text(
     'Hello from flutter man',
     maxLines: 5,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this using only one example, please do test more.

```
void main() {
  int wrapLength = 15;
  String inputText = 'An example of a long word is: Supercalifragulistic';
  String outputText = wrapText(inputText, wrapLength);
  print(outputText);
}

String wrapText(String inputText, int wrapLength){
  List<String> separatedWords = inputText.split(' ');
  StringBuffer intermidiateText = StringBuffer();
  StringBuffer outputText = StringBuffer();
  
  for(String word in separatedWords){
    
    if((intermidiateText.length + word.length) >= wrapLength){
      intermidiateText.write('\n'); 
      outputText.write(intermidiateText);
      intermidiateText.clear();
      intermidiateText.write('$word ');
    } else {
      intermidiateText.write('$word ');
    }
    
  }
  
  outputText.write(intermidiateText); //Write any remaining word at the end
  intermidiateText.clear();
  return outputText.toString().trim();
}
```

Output:

```
An example of 
a long word 
is: 
Supercalifragulistic
```

There would be much simpler and efficient ways to do the same but this crude version works.

Also came across this implementation detail of `php` version of the [wordwrap method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#107570) that uses `regex`. If anyone can convert to dart it would be much better than above solution.